# Swift: Working with Calendar.component causes App to freeze without any Runtime Error?

Tags: swift, xcode, date, swiftui, calendar

**Context:**

I have a `custom Day Struct` which internally uses a `Swift Date Property`. I would this `Struct` be able to check, if another given day is the same weekday as the `Day Struct` itself. However, every time this `Code` gets executed, my `App` freezes without any `Runtime Error`.

---

**Code**

```swift
struct Day: Hashable {
    private let calendar: Calendar = .current
    let date: Date

    static func == (lhs: Day, rhs: Day) -> Bool {
        return Calendar.current.isDate(lhs.date, inSameDayAs: rhs.date)
    }

    func isSameDayOfTheWeek(as day: Day) -> Bool {
        // Replacing this Line to RETURN TRUE prevents the Crash.
        return calendar.component(.weekday, from: self.date) == calendar.component(.weekday, from: day.date)
    }
}

enum Time: Int16, Comparable, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    case morning, noon, evening, night
    
    var id: Int16 { self.rawValue }
    var name: String { ... }
}

struct ToDo: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let block: Block // NSManagedObject
    let day: Day
    let time: Time
}

struct ToDoView: View {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.creationTS)]) private var blocks: FetchedResults<Block>

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(toDos) { toDo in
            Text(toDo.name)
        }
    }

    private var toDos: [ToDo] {
        var toDos: [ToDo] = []

        for block in blocks {
            let startDay: Day = block.safeStartDay

            var day: Day = .today
            while day >= startDay {
                // Removing this Line prevents the Crash.
                guard startDay.isSameDayOfTheWeek(as: day) else { continue }

                for time in Time.allCases {
                    toDos.append(ToDo(block: block, day: day, time: time))
                }

                day = day - 1
            }
        }

        return toDos
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

How can I solve this `Crash` and still be able to check if another given day is the same weekday as the `Day Struct` itself?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of calling the `isSameDayOfTheWeek` method and freezing. I tried it with the current date and it returned true.

Comment: your code works well for me in my tests, no crash. The error/crash must be somewhere else.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you for your Answer. I added more Code Context to make the Crash reproducible. Can you spot any cause?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Thank you for your Answer. I added more Code Context to make the Crash reproducible. Can you spot any cause?

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks a lot for your answer, changing `Day` before `Continue` solved the problem and removed the `Infinite Loop`. Totally overseen this. They also should always use the same `Calendar`, since it's always initialised as the `Current` one. Feel free to post it as an answer, so that I can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that in the loop, if `isSameDayOfTheWeek` returns false, then the loop never exits because you don't change `day` before continue.

A *quick* fix is to just add `day = day - 1` before `continue`, but a much better solution would be to conform `Day` to `Strideable`, so that you could do something like:

```
for day in stride(from: .today, through: startDay, step: -1) {
    ...
}
```

Then just doing `continue` would work as you had expected.

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do here, you can implement `Strideable` like this:

```
func distance(to other: Day) -> Int {
    calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: self.date, to: other.date).day!
}

func advanced(by n: Int) -> Day {
    guard let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: n, to: self.date) else {
        fatalError("No such date: \(n) days after \(self.date)")
    }
    return Day(date: date)
}
```

A note on the `calendar`: by initialising it to `current`, two instances of your struct could have end up with different calendars which have different timezones if the user decides to change it at some point.

```
let day1 = Day(...)

// some time later...

let day2 = Day(...)
```

Then comparing `day1` and `day2` could have some unexpected results:

```
day1.isSameDayOfTheWeek(as: day2) // true, because they are in the same day in day1's timezone
day2.isSameDayOfTheWeek(as: day1) // false, because they are not in the same day in day2's timezone
```

I would recommend using a fixed, `static`, calendar.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful answer! I just implemented `Stridable` and it makes the `Code` much cleaner. I also made the `Calendar Property` `Static`, like you suggested.